# Mean value property over balls with $u$ just continuous?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Mean value property over balls with $u$ just continuous?

I know it can be showed to $u \in C^2$ using Divergence theorem, but for just $u \in C$, how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

You can uniformly approximate a continuous function by $C^2$ functions.

Comment: Which means what? Taylor series?

Comment: E.g. convolution with a bump function.

Comment: How's this related to the MVP?